# bigquery: find following row matching condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm looking at text sequences in BigQuery and trying to identify word completions over a number of rows (sharing an ID). The data looks like:

```
ID, Text
1, t
1, th
1, the
1, the
1, the c
1, the ca
1, the cat
1, the cat 
1, the cat s
...
1, the cat sat on the mat
2, r
...
```

For each given ID and sequence i'm trying to find the next word boundary. So the ideal output would be:

```
ID, Text, Boundary
1, t, the
1, th, the
1, the c, the cat
1, the ca, the cat
1, the cat s, the cat sat
```

In the above the next subsequent row that both shares an ID and ends in a space gives the next (there can be multiple) word completion boundary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Note: it is brute force approach so query is not that elegant as potentially can be - but hope this will give you good start

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, item, boundary
FROM (
  SELECT id, grp, 
    STRING_AGG(IF(boundary, text, ''), '') boundary,
    ARRAY_AGG(IF(NOT boundary, text, NULL) IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY LENGTH(text)) items
  FROM (
    SELECT id, text, 
      LENGTH(text) - LENGTH(REPLACE(text, ' ', '')) - IF(SUBSTR(text, -1) = ' ', 1, 0) grp,
      SUBSTR(text, -1) = ' ' boundary
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
  GROUP BY id, grp
), UNNEST(items) item WITH OFFSET pos
WHERE RTRIM(item) != RTRIM(boundary)
```

if to apply to dummy data in your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 't' text UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'th' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'the' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'the ' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'the c' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'the ca' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'the cat' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'the cat ' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'the cat s' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'the cat sat ' 
)
SELECT id, item, boundary
FROM (
  SELECT id, grp, 
    STRING_AGG(IF(boundary, text, ''), '') boundary,
    ARRAY_AGG(IF(NOT boundary, text, NULL) IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY LENGTH(text)) items
  FROM (
    SELECT id, text, 
      LENGTH(text) - LENGTH(REPLACE(text, ' ', '')) - IF(SUBSTR(text, -1) = ' ', 1, 0) grp,
      SUBSTR(text, -1) = ' ' boundary
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
  GROUP BY id, grp
), UNNEST(items) item WITH OFFSET pos
WHERE RTRIM(item) != RTRIM(boundary)
ORDER BY id, grp, pos
```

result is

```
Row     id      item        boundary     
1       1       t           the  
2       1       th          the  
3       1       the c       the cat  
4       1       the ca      the cat  
5       1       the cat s   the cat sat
```

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery UDF's come in handy in these situations. Here is a working solution:

```
#standardSQL
/*boundary function*/
create temp function boundaryf (text string, sentence string) as (
  array_to_string(array(
    select q.w from unnest(
      array(select struct(w as w, row_number() over () as i)  from unnest(split(sentence, ' ')) w
      ) 
    ) q
    -- respect the ending space
    where q.i <= array_length(split(text, ' ')) - (length(text) - length(rtrim(text)))
  ), ' ')
);

WITH items AS (
  #--your data. assuming this is already ordered
  SELECT 1 as id, 't' as text UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'th' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'the' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'the ' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'the c' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'the ca' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'the cat' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'the cat ' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'the cat s' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'the cat sa' union all
  SELECT 1, 'the cat sat' union all
  SELECT 1, 'the cat sat ' union all
  SELECT 1, 'the cat sat o' union all 
  SELECT 1, 'the cat sat on' union all
  SELECT 1, 'the cat sat on ' union all
  SELECT 1, 'the cat sat on a' union all
  SELECT 1, 'the cat sat on a ' union all
  SELECT 1, 'the cat sat on a m' union all
  SELECT 1, 'the cat sat on a ma' union all
  SELECT 1, 'the cat sat on a mat' union all
  select 2, 'i' union all
  select 2, 'i a' union all
  select 2, 'i am' union all
  select 2, 'i am f' union all
  select 2, 'i am fr' union all
  select 2, 'i am fre' union all
  select 2, 'i am free'
),
sentences as (
  select id, sentences[offset (array_length(sentences)-1)] as sentence from (
    select id, array_agg(text) as sentences 
    from items group by 1
  )
),
control as (
  select i.id, i.text, boundaryf(i.text, s.sentence) as boundary
  from items i
  left join sentences s on s.id  = i.id
)
select * from control
```